# Kafka Connect Design suggestion

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Please suggest or guide me to the design of Apache Kafka connect for the scenario:

Source MySQL: 100GB , approx 300+ tables
Target: PostgreSQL

Please let me know how many source connectors, topics, partion per topic and
number of sink connectors need to design approximately.

Do I need to use Debezium connectors only?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". You'll need to use the JDBC Sink connector for writing to Postgres. This does not mean you cannot install it without running Confluent **Platform** (which includes Apache Kafka, and Kafka includes Kafka Connect)

Answer (score 0):

As Apache Community recommended, The https://debezium.io/ Project provides a collection of high-quality, open source, change capture connectors for a variety
of databases. If you are planning on streaming data from a relational
database to Kafka, it is highly recommend using a Debezium
change capture connector if one exists for your database. In addition, the Debezium documentation is one of the best we’ve seen— in addition to documenting the connectors themselves, it covers useful design patterns and use cases related to change data capture, especially in the context of microservices.

You can also refer sample connectors https://github.com/wushujames/kafka-mysql-connector

And the performance parameters will be purely driven from your current infrastructure setup. As you know, there are many variants of KAFKA Connectors (Source/Sink), and each behaves differently in the runtime.

We had a very complex event processing requirements as yours, sourcing CDC from Oracle and we had to the Golden Gate Connector and it is yet another flavour which may caters most of your requirements in terms of the Performance and Resiliency.

Refer : https://dzone.com/articles/creates-a-cdc-stream-from-oracle-database-to-kafka

Comment: Unclear how this answers the actual question about number of partitions, connectors, etc

Comment: How do you define or derive number of partitions and connectors without knowing their target infrastructure?

Comment: The question said the target is Postgres. Feel free to comment above asking any qualifying questions